# Regex, MVS does not like my Regex strings, how do I make it comply

Tags: c#, regex

So in microsoft visual studio I have a string that is compiled into a regex. My string is "#(\d+(.\d+)?)=(\d+(.\d+)?)". I cannot compile my program because I get an error saying that \d is a unrecognized escape character. How do I tell it to shut up and let me regex like a pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin your string with `@`, that causes the compiler to leave (almost) all characters alone, unescaped (the exception is `"`, which can be escaped as `""`):

```
@"#(\d+(.\d+)?)=(\d+(.\d+)?"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a normal string, you need to escape your backslashes, like so:

```
"#(\\d+(.\\d+)?)=(\\d+(.\\d+)?)"
```

Basically, you're putting a literal string into C#; the C# compiler sees the string first, and tries to interpret `\d` as an escape sequence (which doesn't exist, hence error). Therefore, you use `\\d` to get the C# compiler to see the string as `\d`, which then gets passed to the regex engine (which *does* recognize `\d` as something meaningful). (yes, if you want to match a literal backslash in your regex pattern, you need to use `\\\\`)

But in C#, you have the alternative of just prepending the string with `@` to get the compiler to leave the string alone (though `"` still needs escaping), so that would be like this:

```
@"#(\d+(.\d+)?)=(\d+(.\d+)?)"
```

Comment: `@` is much easier on the eyes than `\\\\`

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Truth, added that. I don't really know C#, just regex.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a verbatim string literal (I prefer to use these because of readability).

Use `@"(#\d+(.\d+)?)=(\d+(.\d+)?)"`

The `@"` sign indicates that the string shouldn't interpret escaped characters (A character prefixed by a `\`) until the closing `"` is reached.

Note: You can match a single `"` in your search pattern by double quoting instead `""`. For instance you can match `"Hello"` by using the pattern `@"""\w+"""`

Comment: To be precise, the backslah won't be interpreted. In replacement, type 2 `"` to get 1.

Comment: Nit-picky :P But you are totally correct! In my comment about it not being interpreted until the next `"` was reached I meant to say that escape characters wouldn't be interpreted by the compiler. And It was also wrong of me to say until the next `"` was reached as you pointed out you can double quote to match a single quote in the pattern. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that c# does not like the `\d` inside the string. Use a verbatim string instead

```
string pattern = @"#(\d+(.\d+)?)=(\d+(.\d+)?)";
```

The "@" denotes it. C# will not look for escape sequences in the string. If you have to escape a `"` use two `""`.

Of cause you can use normal strings. but then you will have to escape the backslashes

```
string pattern = "#(\\d+(.\\d+)?)=(\\d+(.\\d+)?)";
```